# java.lang.VerifyError on finger print dialog API 19, Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, android-fingerprint-api

I am facing with issue when my flow supposed to open the fingerprint dialog.
However I am aware that API 19 doesn't support Fingerprint authentication tho my FingerPrintDialog class checks the current version and it supposed to handle it there.

I debug it and see that the app crashes over here before get into the FingerPrintDialog class.

```
FingerPrintDialog fingerPrintDialog = FingerPrintDialog.newInstance(cardId, userId, purchaseId, savedCardList, selectedShippingMethod, selectedShippingAddress);
```

And the stacktrace is:

```
08-27 21:32:22.478 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve exception class 155 (Landroid/security/keystore/KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException;)
08-27 21:32:22.478 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x2a
08-27 21:32:22.478 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/bkm/b2c/FingerPrintDialog;.cipherInit ()Z
08-27 21:32:22.478 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x002a
08-27 21:32:22.482 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/bkm/b2c/FingerPrintDialog;.cipherInit ()Z
08-27 21:32:22.482 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c W/dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Lcom/bkm/b2c/FingerPrintDialog;
08-27 21:32:58.049 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-27 21:32:58.049 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cdab20)
08-27 21:32:58.617 24758-24758/com.bkm.b2c E/UncaughtException: java.lang.VerifyError: com/bkm/b2c/FingerPrintDialog
                                                                        at com.bkm.b2c.activity.PaymentCompleteActivity$2.onClick(PaymentCompleteActivity.java:155)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Yes **KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException** looks like cannot handle below API 23 but I already make a version check ahead of it.

I feel like there might be a problem of calling static method *FingerPrintDialog.newInstance* but I am not experienced it so I am not sure.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: You probably did your version check incorrectly.  But since you haven't posted code, we can't tell.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same problem until I found your question and because you mentioned "KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException looks like cannot handle below API 23" You made me realize since KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException might not be available in API 19 Devices, which is what I'm experiencing. So I replaced KeyPermanentlyInvalidException and with a generic "Exception". A round about way of fixing it.

Comment: I have also just experienced this problem. The whole fingerprint scanning logic uses code from API 23 upwards, so why is it just KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException which causes the app to crash on Android 5 devices?

Comment: Gian Patrick Quintana's comment is the answer of this question! Thank you!